# Write large amounts of data at one time with VBA in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have quite a bit of experience with VBA in Excel and have learned that the interaction between VBA and Excel is slow.  Thus, you should read and write large chunks of data at one time instead of one cell at a time.

With VBA in Access, I have very little knowledge/experience, almost none.  Is the same sort of thing possible, reading and writing large chunks of data at once?  Is it as important, i.e., is it possible that maybe it's not as important because the interaction between Access and VBA isn't as slow?  I have no idea.  Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is a spreadsheet, Access is a database management application. You should do a little reading:

[Fundamentals of Relational Database Design, Paul Litwin, 2003](http://r937.com/relational.html)

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I know Excel is a spreadsheet.  I know Access is a database management application.  I'm in the process, just beginning, of reading through Access 2010, the Missing Manual.

Comment: @Graphth The point I am making is that data is handled in a completely different way in a database. Handling lines is what a spreadsheet does well, handling large sets of data is what a database does well, hence the SQL references. For example, in your comment to webturner, you mention lines, these would be joined with an INNER JOIN in a database. The query can be built with the query design window. No code would be required.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where your data is coming from, if you have it in a format such as CSV or Excel then you can load it as one block and this is quite quick. The same applies to different database formats and ODBC connections, MS Access can process these quite quickly.

In fact there isn't usually much call for reading and writing large chunks of data using VBA at all. Even with some of the most powerful database servers [RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) (Row By Agonising Row) processing can cause a system to grind to a halt. VBA in Access is no exception to this, it's probably very similar to VBA in excel in this respect.

VBA in MS Access is usually used to improve user experience with automation, to speed up complex calculations and repetitive user tasks.

Comment: The reason I asked is because at work I have some code, written by someone else a few years ago, that does a task field by field.  The code is taking a bunch of data, where one policy may have 1 to 8 different rows of data depending on the policy, and putting all the data from one policy onto one line.  I'm asking if there's a better way.  I don't know how to do this any way in Access, though maybe there is some easy way.  So, it's done in VBA very slowly.

Comment: Ye gods yes! Ask a new question, describe what is being done, give sample inputs and outputs, and ask how to do it better than the current vba. You will have an answer pretty quick.

Comment: Alright, I'll ask a new question.  I did learn a bit from your answers and discovered the Cross Tab query based on Remou's comment.  That almost does what I want but not quite...